# Write Access Client App for SQL Server 2005 Backend

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access, windows-server-2008, database-connection

I'm writing an inventory/payroll system, and I'm storing all the records on a remote server running SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I was wondering how I could start writing forms(very basic) in MS-ACCESS 2010 to upload things to the database. I just want to test it out to make sure that once I implement the entire database, things will work smoothly and without error. I want to figure out how to just make a single form that will be connected to the database, right now the form will just be a simple single text input with a submit button, that will be uploading barcodes(strings not images).

If I need to clarify anything, please just ask.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Oh, darn diddly, thank you for catching that. I mean Access Client. I'll try to edit that now.

Comment: Sure, no need to swear though. :-)

Comment: Fixed it for you. Do you happen to know how I could test the connectivity to my SQL backend through access?

Comment: Sorry, no, Access isn't my forte. At all. I originally opened the question because of the ASP in the title. Which actually means you fixed it for you, because now you're at least as likely to get Access gurus here.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-access-to-build-a-front-end-for-sql-server/5065669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has tons of useful "Getting Started" articles.

This one explains how to connect to SQL Server: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-access-to-sql-server-data-HA010341762.aspx

This one covers all sorts of forms: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/CH010369205.aspx

Go there, you will find a lot that can help you with whatever you are going to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found these guides, and for some reason cannot figure out the Server Name when setting up the DSN. Do you by chance know how I could find out the name/IP of the server? If you don't, no worries.

Comment: you can get IP (if you need one) by pinging it (in command prompt): ping mail.blahblah.com

Comment: This post might be useful in case your SQL Server does not allow remote connections: http://serverfault.com/questions/58579/cannot-connect-to-sql-server

Comment: By the way, for named instance of SQL Server, the connection string should include both parts. E.g. **mail.blahblah.com\instancename**. Where *mail.blahblah.com* is your server's name and *instancename* is the instance's name

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. I feel like mail.blahblah.com may be wrong. I've tried blahblah.com, I've tried the straight IP addresses for both mail.blahblah.com and blahblah.com. I am having trouble finding the server name.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Open SQL Server Management Studio and right-click on the SQL Connection -> Properties -> View Connection Properties (blue hyperlink in the left pane). You will see the info unless it is Azure :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the Server Name. It says

    TERM\SQLEXPRESS

When I enter TERM\SQLEXPRESS for the server name, I still get the error: Server does not exist or Access Denied

If you don't want to help me anymore I understand, you have helped me a lot so far.

Comment: If you are in different domain, just server name will not work. Use full name servername.domain\instance or IP\instancename (in some cases). It is very hard to troubleshoot in the comments area. I would suggest trying to get it working in Windows ODBC settings. then, proceed with Access. Try to create an ODBC connection in ODBC Manager

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have the SQL Client driver installed on the workstation where you'll be using MS Access. You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17943) (look for sqlcnli).
2. The simplest way to get started is to build an ODBC DSN. Access can then link to your SQL Server tables using that DSN. [How to Create a DSN](https://www.google.com/?q=how+to+dsn+sql+server)
3. In Access, Go to the "External Data" option and choose ODBC. Locate your DSN and then select which tables you want Access to be linked to.
4. After your linked tables are showing up in the tables list, click on one of the tables, go to the Create tab (2007, not sure about 2010) and choose Form. This should automatically create a form for you using the table you had selected when you clicked the Form button. There's no need to write code or add buttons to this form. The default form can do all CRUD operations as long as permissions for all CRUD have been granted to the username you used when you created your DSN.

Some developers prefer to use ADO (code only, no linked tables or form wizards) or Pass Through Queries to access SQL Server from Access. I can't really tell you what you should be using because it depends on so many different factors including (but not limited to) size of project, amount of records, skill level, personal preferences, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been at this for hours and haven't gotten many responses. I have a specific problem now, and I'm not sure if you'll know the answer to it but I figure it's worth a try. For creating the DSN, I can't figure out the server name. The only contact I have had with the server up to this point is through an .RDP file, and the domain that is uses is mail.blahblah.com, where blahblah is the domain name. Should I be using this mail prefix, or should I drop it, or use another one? I just can't figure out the name of the server(I know the name of the instance).

Thanks